# Inserting a blank value when pulling data from a Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I am pulling data from a google spreadsheet to go into a google doc.  When I run the query from one part of the spreadsheet to get the values, I use this formula:

```
=QUERY('Announcements'!B2:C30;"select * where B contains 'Primary'")
```

It reads the values in that range and inserts any that match into the column.  The column next to it has:

```
=CONTINUE(E2, 1, 2)
```

While that works, if there isn't any data in the column that matches "Primary" the formula outputs a #N/A in the first cell.  When the script runs to collect the values, it inserts a #VALUE! into the output.  What I would like to do is just insert a blank into the form if that happens.

I believe that I need to use the IFERROR in my initial query but I have been having trouble getting it to work.  I have tried placing it at the front and back of the query without success.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you,

Paul

Answer (score 1):

The function ISERROR detects more errors and it is documented here: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093349

```
ISERROR(value)
value - The value to be verified as an error type.
ISERROR returns TRUE if value is any error, including #DIV/0!, #N/A, #NAME?,#NULL!, #NUM!, #VALUE!, and #REF!.
```

Try to edit the formula to be:

```
=IF (ISERROR(QUERY('Announcements'!B2:C30;"select * where B contains 'Primary'")), "", QUERY('Announcements'!B2:C30;"select * where B contains 'Primary'"))
```

Comment: Hi AboSadiq,

This is really close.  Is there a way to make the adjoining cell in my spreadsheet blank if this one is blank?  Right now it inserts a #VALUE! into the google doc.  The cell that it is pulling from has the formula

    =CONTINUE(E2, 1, 2)

Thank you,

Paul